How to combine multiple GIFs together using discord.js?
I have faced many problems in solving this problem. Knowing that I tried all the solutions online and none of the methods worked for me.
I want to create a method like this on discord.js
https://www.photopea.com/tuts/combine-multiple-gifs-together/
I only need two images, not multiple images.
I tried to create it, but the result shows a static image, not an animated image. It's supposed to be an animated gif
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('photo')
    .setDescription('Merge the user profile picture with a provided GIF image and return the result.'),
  async execute(interaction) {
    try {
      
      if (!interaction.deferred) {
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: false });
      }

      
      const userAvatarURL = interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png', size: 256 });
      

      const providedGIFURL = 'url_gif';
      const providedGIFResponse = await fetch(providedGIFURL);
      const providedGIFBuffer = await providedGIFResponse.buffer();
      

      const [userAvatar, providedGIF] = await Promise.all([
        loadImage(userAvatarURL),
        loadImage(providedGIFBuffer)
      ]);


      const canvas = createCanvas(userAvatar.width, userAvatar.height);
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


      ctx.drawImage(userAvatar, 0, 0);


      ctx.drawImage(providedGIF, 0, 0, userAvatar.width, userAvatar.height);


      const resultBuffer = canvas.toBuffer();


      const attachment = new MessageAttachment(resultBuffer, 'result.gif');
      await interaction.followUp({ files: [attachment] });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error);
      await interaction.followUp('An error occurred while processing your request.');
    }
  }
};

If someone knows this method I would be grateful to him.
Thank you,
